# Picture-Puzzle. Find the number!

Tags: cipher, visual, calculation-puzzle, geometry

Make sense out of this picture below and find the two-digit number!

[image]

Note: Pay attention to everything except the rounded rectangles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Second attempt**

The two-digit number is:

> 18

I calculated it as follows:

> The two-digit value is the **sum** of the lengths of the three colored lines.
>  The three objects (hexagon, square, octagon) give numeric values (6, 4, 8) corresponding to the number of sides, and the square brackets denote squaring the values inside. For the circle, the area is 6 squared π = 36π, so the radius (red line) is **6**. For the triangle, the area is 4 squared = 16, so the length of the hypotenuse is **8**. For the square, the area is 8, so the gray line is length **4**. The sum of these lengths is 6 + 8 + 4 = 18.

**Previous attempt**

I will take a stab at it, and guess that the two-digit number is:

> 14

I calculated it as follows:

> The lengths of the colored lines correspond to the number of letters in the color, so the red line is length 3, yellow is 6, and gray is 4.
>  The areas of the three objects are thus: 9π, 9, and 8.
>  I am assuming that the information inside each of the rounded rectangles denotes the area of the object, and that the square brackets denote squaring of the quantity inside.
>  With that assumption, the hexagon represents 3, the square 3, and the octagon 8. 
>  Adding these values of these three shapes produces 14.

Comment: Great answer, but not the intended one! The colors could of been green, purple, orange or any other color. So the colors do not matter. I just wanted to highlight those distances. But you managed to decipher quite a bit so you're very close. Re-think and im sure you'll get this :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I revised my answer.

Comment: Now it's the intended one! Well done :)